# Dealing Options from a Map.get in Scala

Tags: scala, monads, scala-option

I've a Scala `Map` that contains a bunch of parameters that I get in a HTTP request.

```
val queryParams = Map( ("keyword" -> "k"), ("from" -> "f"), ("to" -> "t"), ("limit" -> "l") )
```

I've a method that takes all these parameters.

```
def someMethod( keyword: String, from: String, to: String, limit: String) = { //do something with input params }
```

I want to pass the parameters from the map into my method `someMethod`.

`queryParams.get` returns an `Option`. So I can call something like `queryParams.get("keyword").getOrElse("")` for each input parameter.

```
someMethod( queryParams.get("keyword").getOrElse(""), queryParams.get("from").getOrElse(""), queryParams.get("to").getOrElse(""), queryParams.get("limit").getOrElse(""))
```

Is there a better way ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If all the parameters have the same default value you can set a [default value](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Map@withDefaultValue[B1%3E:B]%28d:B1%29:scala.collection.immutable.Map[A,B1]) to the entire Map:

```
val queryParams = Map( ("keyword" -> "k"), ("from" -> "f"), ("to" -> "t"), ("limit" -> "l") ).withDefaultValue("")
someMethod( queryParams("keyword"), queryParams("from"), queryParams("to"), queryParams("limit"))
```

`withDefaultValue` return a Map which for any non exist value return the default value. Now that you are sure you always get a value you can use `queryParams("keyword")` (without the get function).